# jquery jqgrid unformatter for SEARCH filter

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have this column in my grid called TIME which displays LOCAL time in the format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss AM/Pm format. This is done by the formatter function. In the database it is stored in the UTC format. So obviously i need a conversion BACK. It seems the unformat option doesnt work for the search filter. any idea on how to make my conversion function call on hitting the FIND button?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an ideal solution but you could just do the unformatting on the server-side. For conversion back to UTC you can use JavaScript to determine the client's time zone. Here is one example from a quick search, there are probably others if you decide to go down this route:

- [Automatic time zone detection using JavaScript php](http://bharatbaba.com/blog/automatic-client-side-time-zone-detection-using-javascript-php/)

Comment: thanks for the reply.. i WAS initially trying out in the server side. But java time conversion is quite bad in my opinion. I did manage to get the client timezone by using getLocale(), but then while conversion process gave me no results. So i resorted back to jqgrid. Thanks anyway.